# Recursive / Occurrence logic with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering if anybody can shed some lights on something I've recently stuck with.

Let's say the following SQL table holds the information of people, their uniqueID, their joining date and user type.

```
GroupID UserID     Date        UserType 
2        1         01/01/2020  Admin        
2        2         21/02/2020  Admin        
2        3         23/02/2020  User         
2        4         25/03/2020  User         
2        5         30/03/2020  Admin        
2        6         11/04/2020  Admin        
2        7         12/04/2020  User         
2        8         21/04/2020  Admin
```

In order to achieve "grouping" column result; (bear in mind they are sorted by date)

```
PlaceID  UserID    Date        UserType     Grouping
2        1         01/01/2020  Admin        1
2        2         21/02/2020  Admin        2
2        3         23/02/2020  User         2
2        4         25/03/2020  User         2
2        5         30/03/2020  Admin        3
2        6         11/04/2020  Admin        4
2        7         12/04/2020  User         4
2        8         21/04/2020  Admin        5
```

what should be the query ?

**Logic behind the grouping column is**
Every admin user type will get a new grouping ID but their follower Users (ordered by date) will get the same grouping with their previous admin. Also PlaceID is 2 here but this logic will replicate for other placeIDs.

Thanks,

Comment: PostgreSQL, on AWS Redshift

Comment: I'd suggest approaching this in 2 steps: ID Generation for the admins (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html), and then using the lead function, with an ordering expression (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to fill in the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` to see if the value changes and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter (where prev_usertype is distinct from usertype) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             lag(usertype) over (partition by placeid order by date) as prev_usertype
      from t
     ) t
```